# Impact of Parentheses on Methods and 'Self' Variable

Tags: python, class, oop

I've been learning some of the basics of OOP implementation in Python. I was experimenting, and noticed that when I didn't add parentheses when defining an object, methods in the class required me to define self.

Because I'm new to OOP I don't really know where to get an answer to a niche question like this other than posting a question a stackoverflow.

To make this a little more concrete, here's the code I was running:

```
class Person():
    def introduction(self):
        print(f"Hi, my name's {self.name}. What's yours?")

Aaron = Person
Aaron.name = "Aaron"
Aaron.introduction()

Betty = Person()
Betty.name = "Betty"
Betty.introduction()
```

In the former case the method introduction requires me to input Aaron again for it to work, or else it tells me I'm missing the argument for the variable 'self'. However, in the latter case I do not need to redefine the 'self' variable. Why is this?

Comment: does the first variant really work? you are just giving your class a new name. `Aaron.introduction()` should fail because it is missing an argument. the sensible thing here would be to create an `def __init__(self, name): self.name = name` and instantiate with `Aaron=Person(name="Aaron")`.

Comment: Please learn about namespaces

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are just aliasing the `Person` class to a variable called `Aaron`.  After doing that if you called `Aaron()`, you would get a new instantiation of a `Person` object.

It is much the same as if you define a function, then assign a variable to the function without parenthesis.

```py
def hello():
    print('hello')

world = hello

world()
# prints:
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't defining an object when you omit parentheses, you are simply assigning the class object to another variable. The same thing as if you had done:

```
a = []
b = a
```

Now both `a` and `b` reference the same list object. Similarly,

```
Aaron = Person
```

Just means `Aaron` and `Person` both reference the same class object - classes are objects, everything is an object in Python.

Note, Python's object model is pretty simple, `instance.method()` is equivalent to `InstanceClass.method(instance)`. The only "magic" that happens in methods is that if a method *is accessed through an instance*, what is actually returned is a bound method, which has bound the instance as the first argument to the function.

A function defined on a class is just an attribute, and when you access it, you get the original function.

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self): return 42
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar # instance binding magic
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x1039215c0>>
>>> Foo.bar
<function Foo.bar at 0x103907950>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: class Person(): 
   ...:     def introduction(self): 
   ...:         print(f"Hi, my name's {self.name}. What's yours?") 
   ...:
```

`Person` is the class:

```
In [2]: Person                                                                                               
Out[2]: __main__.Person
```

`introduction` is a class method.  It should be called via an instance, not the class itself.  If called via the class, it's just like calling a function, which requires correct arguments:

```
In [3]: Person.introduction()                                                                                
....
TypeError: introduction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

In [4]: Person.introduction('foobar')                                                                        
...
<ipython-input-1-3d4d3d4fd6be> in introduction(self)
      1 class Person():
      2     def introduction(self):
----> 3         print(f"Hi, my name's {self.name}. What's yours?")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Your `Aaron=Person` assignment is just a distraction.  It doesn't create anything new.  It's just another way of referencing the class.

Defining a class instance:

```
In [5]: betty = Person()                                                                                     
In [6]: betty                                                                                                
Out[6]: <__main__.Person at 0x7f44603ccb00>
```

Now if we use the `introduction` method, `self` is the instance itself. But as in the previous call, the `self` needs a `name`:

```
In [7]: betty.introduction()                                                                                 
....
<ipython-input-1-3d4d3d4fd6be> in introduction(self)
      1 class Person():
      2     def introduction(self):
----> 3         print(f"Hi, my name's {self.name}. What's yours?")

AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'name'
```

As you do, we can assign an attribute to the instance (but usually we do that kind of assignment in the `__init__`):

```
In [8]: betty.name = 'foobar'                                                                                
In [9]: betty.introduction()                                                                                 
Hi, my name's foobar. What's yours?
```

A more complete class definition should have an `__init__` and a display method:

```
In [10]: class Person(): 
    ...:     def __init__(self, name): 
    ...:         self.name = name 

    ...:     def introduction(self): 
    ...:         print(f"Hi, my name's {self.name}. What's yours?") 

    ...:     def __repr__(self): 
    ...:         return f'Person named {self.name}' 
    ...:                                                                                                     
In [11]: betty=Person('betty')                                                                               
In [12]: betty                                                                                               
Out[12]: Person named betty      # the repr display
In [13]: betty.introduction()                                                                                
Hi, my name's betty. What's yours?
```

If you do want to call a method via `Person.func` define it as a `classmethod`.  But that's an advanced topic that can wait.

If I add to the class definition:

```
...:     @classmethod 
...:     def classintro(cls): 
...:         return f'Person class name is {cls.name}' 
...:     name = 'Person'
```

The class now has a `name` attribute, and method to display it:

```
In [23]: Person.name                                                                                         
Out[23]: 'Person'
In [24]: Person.classintro()                                                                                 
Out[24]: 'Person class name is Person'
```

and the instance can access both methods:

```
In [25]: betty = Person('betty')                                                                             
In [26]: betty.introduction()                                                                                
Hi, my name's betty. What's yours?
In [27]: betty.classintro()                                                                                  
Out[27]: 'Person class name is Person'
```